# How to open a PDF file?

Tags: visual-c++

I want to load a pdf file on the click of a button.
In the OnClickButton() implementation I am writing the function which open the PDF file

```
ShellExecute(0,
             "Open",
             "%s\\HELP\\RiverCADPro_User_Manual.pdf",
             NULL,
             NULL,
             SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

The above code is not working.What else is to be needed so as to run the above code

Comment: What is the %s in your path string?

Comment: pls be more specific; what's the error message etc...

Answer (score 1):

Make your path an absolute path. Maybe the contained `%s` is meant to be substituted by the beginning of the actual path?

Are you missing some kind of

```
sprintf(
  szBuffer,
  "%s\\HELP\\RiverCADPro_User_Manual.pdf",
  szBasePath);
```

in your code?